# Simple concept check

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Say I have a simple template like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A {};
```

And I want to specify that the type-parameter `T` is of some unrelated type `X<U>` where `U` is not known (or unspecifyable).

Is there a way how to express that as a concept?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there a way how to express that as a concept?

You don't need a concept, class template specialization works just fine in your case.
As an example, you can do this:

```
template<typename T>
class A;

template<typename U>
class A<X<U>> { /* ... */ };
```

This way, unless `A` is instantiated with a type of the form `X<U>` (where `U` is unknown), you'll get a compile-time error because the primary template isn't defined. In other terms, it won't work for all the types but `X<U>` (for each `U`), where the latter matches the class template specialization that has a proper definition.

Note that I assumed `X` is a known type. That's not clear from your question.
Anyway, if it's not and you want to accept types of the form `X<U>` for each `X` and each `U`, you can still do this:

```
template<typename T>
class A;

template<template<typename> class X, typename U>
class A<X<U>> { /* ... */ };
```

---

As a minimal, working example:

```
template<typename>
struct S {};

template<typename>
class A;

template<typename U>
class A<S<U>> {};

int main() {
    A<S<int>> aSInt;
    A<S<double>> aSDouble;
    // A<char> aChar;
}
```

Both `A<S<int>>` and `A<S<double>>` are fine and the example compiles. If you toggle the comment, it won't compile anymore for `A<char>` isn't defined at all.

---

As a side note, if you don't want to use class template specialization and you want to simulate concepts (remember that they are not part of the standard yet and they won't be at least until 2020), you can do something like this:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename>
struct X {};

template<typename>
struct is_xu: std::false_type {};

template<typename U>
struct is_xu<X<U>>: std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct A {
    static_assert(is_xu<T>::value, "!");
    // ...
};

int main() {
    A<X<int>> aXInt;
    A<X<double>> aXDouble;
    // A<char> aChar;
}
```

That is, given a generic type `T`, static assert its actual type by means of another structure (`is_xu` in the example) that verifies if `T` is of the form `X<U>` (for each `U`) or not.

---

My two cents: the class template specialization is easier to read and understand at a glance.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question

Comment: @Cubbi Good. So I can't actually improve it.

Answer (score 11):

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class C>
concept bool Template = requires (T t) { {t} -> C<auto>; };
```

Now given a class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {};
```

a type template parameter can be constrained using:

```
template <typename T> requires Template<T, X>
class A {};
```

or:

```
template <Template<X> T>
class A {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WYuWbC7tVBFDJDqd)

This will work also for types derived from `X<U>`.

Comment: I would mention that it requires C++2x or later (unfortunately). That being said, is there a good resource to go a bit deeper on concepts that you can suggest? Thank you.

Comment: It just need a compiler that support the concept TS. Clang frontend will soon have it implemented, so Visual Studio will have it too. @PiotrSkotnicki, If you had inverted the template argument of the concept, you could have declared `template<Template<X> T> class A{}`

Comment: @Oliv You are right, but I suspect OP wants a solution that works today, not _soon_. ;-) ... Anyway, I like this answer, do not misunderstand me.

Comment: @Oliv thanks, I couldn't come up with this syntax on my own, although I knew it should be possible

Comment: @skypjack Concepts TS is the only resource I know

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It makes sense actually. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack If you are interested in concept, here is a list of source I have used to learn to use it: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints ], Strousturp guide [http://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf ], and the normative papers (reading it cleaned some misconception I had!) [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4630.pdf ]

Comment: Is the `C<auto>` syntax still correct after http://wg21.link/p0127r2 has been voted into C++17?

Comment: @dyp gcc implemented this auto type deduction in template parameter, and it surprisingly works... It seems that auto is a very special concept that can admit either a type or a value depending on the context...